# Logic apps against EOL Shared MBx

Tags: exchange-server, azure-logic-apps

I am **VERY** new to Azure Logic apps. Please be gentle - but any links to sources of learning will be appreciated as well.

I have a made a simple logic app at the request of the business that answers every e-mail received in a shared mailbox with an autoreply - instead of the standard "one per customer" action of the normal Exchange Online autoresponder.That part works just fine.

We now need to add an action that can delete without replying for specific senders. Why? We "found" another org that must be set up to do the same thing, thus causing a flood of responses between the two org's Autoresponders. Not surprising, but obviously not good.

I'd like to be able to add the relevant address (and be able to add addresses in the future) to a (parallel?) filter, that would prevent this loop from happening. I've tried my best to use the "Delete Email (V2)" built in function for "Office 365 Outlook" but it always ends in a "Resource Not Found (status code: 400)" error and the email isn't deleted/moved to the deleted items folder.

Any ideas how to either get this to work, or a better way to do this job?

Thanks,

Mule

[image: App design and errors]

Answer (score 0):

> I have a made a simple logic app at the request of the business that answers every e-mail received in a shared mailbox with an autoreply - instead of the standard "one per customer" action of the normal Exchange Online autoresponder.That part works just fine.

As mentioned in this statement, we understood that you are using `When a new email arrives (V3)` trigger to give an auto reply.

> I've tried my best to use the "Delete Email (V2)" built in function for "Office 365 Outlook" but it always ends in a "Resource Not Found (status code: 400)" error and the email isn't deleted/moved to the deleted items folder.

To make this work you just need to give the message id from the trigger `When a new email arrives (V3)` and so it deletes the one that has already arrived. You can make required actions in between before deleting the mail.

Considering this to be my logic app

[image]

I could able to get the email content to my logic app from outlook in `Get email (V2)` step and as soon as it completes this action the `Delete email (V2)` executes and deletes the one that just arrived.

Here is the email that I'm receiving

[image]

and the successful run for my logic app

[image]

For more information on logic apps you can refer [Introduction to Azure Logic Apps - Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-logic-apps/?msclkid=7566893ec01111ec88b924bfdd845bc8) and [Azure Logic Apps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/?msclkid=e7a5241ec01111ec8441e26536b55f00)

**REFERENCES:**
[Office 365 Outlook - Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/?msclkid=f2a966b3c01111ec8ff309f5038f8e4e)

Comment: This does help, because I was trying to suss out the "Message ID" logic as well. So thanks for this.

However it only answers part of my question. Maybe I just need clarification? I only want to directly delete new arriving email from a specific address (or preferably an editable array of addresses) that I can set a filter for? All other mail should get the auto response. 

The point is to break the loop when we encounter an autoresponder form another org that also "responds to all emails," thus setting off a never ending cascade of responses. Would you have any ideas on that part?
Thanks

Comment: sure this is possible, You can use [Condition connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement?msclkid=46181afbc0d211ecade35ca164e99985) . Which means that if a particular condition follows then it executes true block else false. Try checking this [image](https://i.imgur.com/M50i9wD.png)

Comment: @swerhakandikonda thanks for your effort.  But this still isn't working. The delete doesn't work.

Comment: @USMAMule well, try sharing what you have tried and what error you are receiving. preferably screenshots of your flow or code from your code view of your logic apps helps us understand where it is going wrong

Comment: I don't seem to be able to add screenshots.  Is it a "too new to Stack" thing?  I'd be happy to send to you directly. (if that's even possible)

Comment: Image added to original question.  I am new so it would only create a link to the images.  Let me know if that worked or not. Thanks again for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately a better answer was to use different variable for the conditional.  Using an OR conditional with several archetypical subject lines, as well as embedding "invisible text" in the body of the original response email was the solution, as Logic Apps seems incapable of pulling the Message ID through the steps.

Thanks for your help @swerhakandikonda.